# Greenplum's FDW tool duplicates data many times

Tags: sql, greenplum

I have Greenplum database version 6.14.1, working on CentOS 7.2 host.

So I try to copy data from Postgres 11 to Greenplum 6.14 by Foreign Data Wrapper.
With default options I receive N rows and all data comes through master node.
So I decide to change options to (mpp_execute "all segment"),
but in this case I receive 24*N rows, because my cluster has 24 segments nodes.

I think this is well known issue, but unfortunately can't find solution at all.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

On Postgres server

```
    create table x(id int, value float8);
    insert into x select r, r * random() from generate_series(1,1000) r;
    select count(*) from x;
    
    1000
    (1 row)
```

On Greenplum server

```
    CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
    create server foreign_server_x FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS(host '172.16.128.135', port '5432', dbname 'postgres');
    
    -- user mapping
    CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user
    SERVER foreign_server_x OPTIONS (user 'admin', password 'admin');
    
    -- foreign table foreign_x
    CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_x
    (id int, value float8) SERVER foreign_server_x OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'x');
    
    select count(*) from foreign_x;
    
    1000
    (1 row)
    
    -- mpp_execute = all segments
    alter foreign table foreign_x options (add mpp_execute 'all segments');
    
    -- foreign_x (24 segments)
    select count(*) from foreign_x;
    
    24000
    (1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be expected behavior since you have 24 segments, and are asking all of them to go query the database. I would suggest trying to execute only from the master, or select a unique count(*), or leverage an external table instead of FDW.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Greenplum team also confirm this point. "All segments"-mode does not work as I expect.